# Autoajustar tamaño DataGridView en funcion del tamaño de las columnas

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid

Tengo un datagridview con varias columnas en una aplicacion de windows forms 2.0, he conseguido que los valores de cada columna queden ajustados en funcion del tamaño del valor de la celda mas larga, para ello uso la pripiedad AutoSizeColumnsMode -> Fill.

Sin embargo no consigo que el total de las columnas quede ajustado, lo que necesito es que el datagridview cambie de tamaño para quedar ajustado,
creo que con una imagen se ve mejor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo ideal seria que el datagrid se estrechara hasta conseguir eliminar el espacio ocupado por el circulo rojo.

He probado varias opciones, entiendo que por programacion se podria hacer, pero quizas exista alguna propiedad o combinacion de varias para lograr este funcionamiento.
Gracias.

Comment: Intenta poniendo en la columna que quieres que crezca `Datagrid.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode =DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;` De todas maneras, para poder ayudarte deberíamos ver exactamente como tienes definido el grid y las columnas

Comment: @pikoh gracias, pero no seria posible ponerlo para que las columnas crezcan para ocupar el tamaño de su celda mayor y que despues el tamaño del datagridview se ajustase automaticamente para que se vieran todos los valores?

Comment: @Veelicus no. No por defecto al menos, por código si sería posible ajustar el tamaño del `DataGridView` al de la suma de las columnas, pero tendría que ser de una forma manual.Al menos, que yo recuerde :)

Comment: @Pikoh gracias, la otra opcion era esa hacerlo por programacion, hubiese estado bien que existiese esa propiedad :(

Comment: De todas maneras, es un poco raro eso. Lo lógico es que el grid tenga siempre el mismo tamaño y sean las columnas las que se adapten (desde el punto de vista estético y de usabilidad), al menos en mi opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas usar la propiedad `DataGridViewColumn.AutoSizeMode`. En el siguiente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666582/datagridview-autofit-and-fill) de StackOverflow en inglés tienes la respuesta que maneja todas las opciones. En cualquier caso, para lo que solicitas esto debe valerte:

```
this.DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

o también:

```
this.DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Saludos.